# Calendar event showing new time change notification every day

Tags: macos, calendar, notifications, exchange

I have a recurring meeting each day on my Exchange calendar at 8:45 AM. In the Calendar application, I get a notification every morning that the event time was updated to 8:45AM. However, the event organizer is not changing the time, and it stays exactly the same.

The only thing I can think of is something odd with time zones and/or Exchange. The organizer is in CST and I'm in Mountain. Calendar correctly shows my time in the event details both before and after getting the alert about the change...

Any idea what is happening and how to stop the daily notification that the time has changed (since it hasn't!).

Example of the notification:

[image: Example notification]

Comment: Is it a local calendar or cloud-based? If the latter you could try deleting it and re-adding.

Comment: It's an Exchange calendar on an Exchange server. Deleting it is not an option.

Comment: Why not? Calendar preferences, Accounts, delete the Exchange account, add it back in again. Done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, a solution.

Unfortunately the meeting organizer will have cancel and recreate the event to solve this problem. The problem is a result of the meeting organizer including themselves as an attendee which creates a sort of loop for meeting updates.

To solve, the organizer must create a new event that does not include themselves as an attendee. If the a distribution list is used, they must expand it and remove their name from the list.

[Answer source.](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/calendar/iphone-and-the-meeting-request-bug/)